# Typeahead populates dropdown with 'undefined' when using AJAX source

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, typeahead

Been working on typeahead, looked up on stackoverflow for solutions but none of them worked.
I am using an ajax source to get JSON data for products, but typeahead returns all the matched values as 'undefined'. Here is the code that i am using.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where did your code go? I'm having this same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestions array should contain objects in the form

```
{value: "test"}
```

so instead of doing

```
products.push(product.sDescription);
```

it should be

```
products.push({ value: product.sDescription });
```